# should i delete these empty keyframes?

Tags: keyframes

say, an animation clip has one piece animated, which moves along one axis, but keyframes will be created for other two axes too. should i delete those?

example: should i delete keyframes in red box, blue box or should i not touch anything at all?
[image]

//edit: does having these affects performance?

Comment: If your animation is truly based on a single axis you can delete the keyframes for the other ones. It does not contribute to the animation nor to your project overview. My guess is you used something in the line of 'auto keys' which will place keys on every given location/rotation/scale regardless of which keys you actualy need.

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes, that's pretty much what i used because that was the only way of adding keyframes that i know. was afraid to remove something that was created automatically, thought it may mess up other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend *Delagone's* comment: It does not matter.

But every time you delete these keys (autokey), you're doing unnecessary work. **Time** which you could spend setting new key, which you need. I advise you to get used to having lots of keys around.

Another pitfall is to accidentally change the transformations later, if you have channels, which aren't keyed, you're going to loose the values you had before. Leave your additional keys in place, even if they don't seem necessary. Quite a lot animators even key all channels regardless how small the amount of channels (bones, etc) is that they changed, just so a characters pose if fixed, no matter what attributes / channels are changed later.

If the additional keys still disturb you, here is a workaround.
After moving your bones / objects to their initial transform, lock all attributes, which you don't want to key. Then create a [button keying set](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html) with the channels you want to animate. Then set the active keying set, to the one you created. If you're using autokey, check the *keying set button* next to the *autokey button*.

Comment: does having a lot of empty keys affects performance? that's what worries me. it makes sense to delete unused hidden geometry for that reason, but i don't know if such "empty" keys should be deleted as well if i'm making an animation for something like a game.

Comment: Definitely delete unused geomertry. I'm pretty sure empty keys won't hurt your performance, but I don't have a source handy.